# In JavaScript there an elegant way to merge two Objects and sum any common properties?

Tags: javascript, merge, mapreduce, duplicates

I'm deduping a large array of Objects, many of which have some properties in common. All of the properties are integers.

It's trivially easy to loop through the keys and merge manually, but I can't help but feel like there's some combination of `Object.assign` and `map` and `reduce` that could do this is one line. As the language matures, it seems worth staying ahead of the curve.

EDIT: As an example:

```
let A = {
  "a": 10,
  "e": 2,
  "g": 14
}

let B = {
  "b": 3,
  "e": 15,
  "f": 1,
  "g": 2,
  "h": 11
}

let C = Object.magicMerge(A, B) 

/*
{
  "a": 10,
  "e": 17,
  "g": 16
  "b": 3,
  "f": 1,
  "h": 11
}
*/
```

Comment: the part that isn't trivially easy is the *sum any common properties*

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all properties are integers". Are all the keys in objects integers (which means they're really strings) or are the values integers? Can you explain more with a sample input/output?

Comment: Added a simple example -- thx!

Comment: Do you want an entirely new object or just `C === A` (as with `Object.assign`)?

Comment: Doesn't matter -- `C === A` is fine but not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something without loops/reduce:

```
let C = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(A)
        .concat(Object.keys(B))
        .map(k => [k,
            (A[k] || 0) + (B[k] || 0)
        ])
)
```

And here's a generic function for any number of objects:

```
let mergeSum = (...objs) => Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(
        new Set(objs.flatMap(Object.keys)),
        k => [k,
            objs
                .map(o => o[k] || 0)
                .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
        ]))

C = mergeSum(A, B)
```

or even more generic:

```
let mergeReduce = (objs, fn, init) => Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(
        new Set(objs.flatMap(Object.keys)),
        k => [k, objs.map(o => o[k]).reduce(fn, init)]
    ));

// for example:

sumOfProps = mergeReduce([A, B],
    (a, b) => (a || 0) + (b || 0))

listOfProps = mergeReduce([A, B],
    (a, b) => b ? a.concat(b) : a,
    [])
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really any shortcut in vanilla JS, you have to explicitly iterate through each object and each property, and sum them up somehow. One option is to group with `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
}, {
  bar: 5,
  baz: 7
}, {
  baz: 10,
  buzz: 10
}];

const combined = arr.reduce((a, obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
    a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + val;
    return a;
  }, a)
, {});

console.log(combined);
```

I prefer `reduce` because the outer `combined` variable, once created, is not mutated within its scope, but you can use `for..of` instead if you wish:

```js
const arr = [{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
}, {
  bar: 5,
  baz: 7
}, {
  baz: 10,
  buzz: 10
}];

const combined = {};
for (const obj of arr) {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    combined[key] = (combined[key] || 0) + val;
  }
}

console.log(combined);
```

Comment: Using `reduce` for the one loop but `forEach` for the other feels really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like:

```js
function objTotals(array){
  const r = {};
  array.forEach(o => {
    for(let i in o){
      if(!(i in r))r[i] = 0;
    }
  });
  for(let i in r){
    array.forEach(o => {
      if(i in o)r[i]+=o[i];
    });
  }
  return r;
}
const a = [{a:0, b:2, c:5, d:1, e:2}, {a:1, b:3}, {a:5, b:7, c:4}, {a:2, b:1, c:9, d:11}];
console.log(objTotals(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way:

```js
const a = { "a": 10, "e": 2, "g": 14 };
const b = { "b": 3, "e": 15, "f": 1, "g": 2, "h": 11 };

const sum = [...Object.entries(a), ...Object.entries(b)]
  .reduce(
    (acc, [key, val]) => ({ ...acc, [key]: (acc[key] || 0) + val }),
    {}
  );
console.log("sum:", sum);
```

One liner as you asked :)
In my opinion it is most elegant way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, seems to me you're going to need to merge the keys then merge the objects. Tried for a simpler solution, but this one (while longer than I like) does the job, and for any number of objects.

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 4,
  c: 2.2,
  d: 43,
  g: -18 
}, object2 = {
  b: -22.4,
  c: 14,
  d: -42,
  f: 13.3
};

// This will take any number of objects, and create
//  a single array of unique keys.
const mergeKeys = (objects)=>{
  let keysArr = objects.reduce((acc, object)=>{
    acc.push(...Object.keys(object));
    acc = [...new Set(acc.sort() )];
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return keysArr;
}

/***
 * this first gets the unique keys, then creates a
 *   merged object. Each object is checked for each
 *   property, and if it exists, we combine them.
 *   if not, we simply keep the current value.
 *
 ***/
const combineAnyNumberOfObjects = (...objects)=>{
  const keys = mergeKeys(objects),
        returnObj = {};
  keys.forEach(key=>{
    returnObj[key]=0;
    objects.forEach(object=>{
      returnObj[key] = !!object[key] ? returnObj[key]+object[key] : returnObj[key]
    })
  })

  return returnObj;
}

console.log(combineAnyNumberOfObjects(object1, object2));
```

As you said, trivially easy to merge and manually add each prop. The one line answer above? Beautiful. ;)

Comment: That `mergeKeys` is totally overcomplicated and inefficient.